# How to access Next.js Application from a fixed Hostname in Local Environment?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dns, localhost, hosts

Let's say I have a Next.js Application. Which is working properly. The application is currently accessible through `http://localhost:4000` or `http://somehostname.local:4000`

here, I have set

`127.0.0.1    somehostname.local`

in my hosts file.

But, I want this Next.js application to only be accessible from `http://somehostname.local:4000` only, in my local environment.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried using `-H` in nextjs scripts? i think this works fine for your situation. see the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server).

Comment: Yeah this seems convincing but still it doesn't prevent this Application to be accessed from `localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit fiddly, but you could try to accomplish this with an Express Server in the background.

Try it out with a server.js in the root folder of your project:

```js
import express from 'express';
import next from 'next';

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {

  const server = express();

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {

    const hostname = req.hostname;

    if(hostname !== 'somehostname.local') {
      res.status(404).end();
      return;
    }

    return handle(req, res);

  });

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
  });

});
```

Then update your `package.json` like this:

```json
"dev": "node server.js",
```

Have not verified this, but should work, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, I had this in mind but I was looking for some other way than to altering the Next Dev Server Implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I can't figure out why you need to block localhost when serving locally?  I'd love to hear your rationale.

You won't be able to achieve this with the default config since the default config is the same as using

```
npm run dev -H localhost
```

and localhost will by default resolve to 127.0.0.1 so localhost and somehostname.local are essentially the same alias in your scenario.  In theory you could remove the localhost alias, but that breaks lots of things and is highly not recommended.

However you can achieve what you want with a firewall and using your local IP.  This is kind of hacky and will break if your network or IP changes, but it's technically possible.

Alias somehostname.local to your local IP address in your hosts file:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx somehostname.local
```

Then run the next server on your alias with

```
npm run dev -H somehostname.local
```

or add it to your scripts or config file.

This will make the next app available on the local network so set your firewall to block lan access to port 4000 and allow local access:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4000 -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4000 -j DROP
```

This will serve on http://somehostname.local:4000 but not on http://localhost:4000.

I still can't imagine a scenario where blocking localhost is important, and since this solution breaks when your local IP changes it seems like a poor approach.  I suppose you could script automatic updates of the firewall rules and hosts file, but why?

Answer (score 1):

That's inevitable, in your hosts file the name `localhost` is referencing the loop IP (*127.0.0.1*), which means your local environment.

So even by using `somehostname.local` which is a new name for the local area, the `localhost` exists.

If you want to use `localhost` for another project, you can use a different port or default port (80) for another project.

If that's your utter decision to have got `somehostname.local` for the current NextJs project and `localhost` for another one even with the same port, you must install and use NGINX on your system to add policies that I won't proffer to you at all.

Comment: I am not trying to use `somehostname.local` for one project and `localhost` for another project. I just want my particular Next application to be accessible only from `somehostname.local`. If I try to access it from `localhost` then it should not serve my Next Application.

Comment: @D_Gamer,  I completely got what was your wish. Using `localhost` for another app or not serving the current app by `localhost` is the same. You wish to have the serving only on `somehostname.local`. That's impossible without configuring a web server. Even [Jake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77953499/6877799) isn't your wish. Because it returns 404 which means the app is being served by `localhost`.